# I'm too shy to ask, so I put on a mask

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme

> I'm too shy to ask,
>   so I put on a mask.
>   Made of bits and pieces
>   I hope my loneliness ceases.
>
> If you think I am the one
>   I'll always be true,
>   but if you think I'm a zero
>   I'll be nothing to you.
>
> I'll give you my numbers
>   you might think they're high
>   but split them in half
>   I might be your guy!

**The numbers:**

```
12645
14073
15201
13925
14196
13550
6497
```

What do I say, and what do you answer?

Comment: So unconventional encoding = puzzles on here? See them a lot lately but I don't get the thrill

Comment: @user1886419 Yes, in my opinion it's considered a puzzle because it fits the [tag:cipher] tag and plus you also have to figure out the algorithm rather than just the encoding/encryption. He also gives enough clues in the riddle in order to do that, which differentiates it from [poor-quality code puzzles](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do). Of course it's a personal preference whether you like these or not, but I certainly think they're on-topic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You said

> `bemyvalentine!`

Because

> Convert all numbers from decimal to binary, then split all results in half and treat them as bytes; Then convert back to ASCII.

And my answer is

> ```
> 11493
> 7404
> 10740
> 13047
> 13541
> 3891
> ```

---

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/dypq8ez6/5/) a (dirty) fiddle for encoding/decoding strings with this technique, with OP's message as initial input. Unfortunately it only works in a specific range on ASCII codes, if for example a space is included it's hard to tell where to split the part in half.

I hope I can motivate more users with this to include such programs for encrypting a self-created cipher in their answers or directly from the questioner in their wrap-up posts.